# Pandas merge two dataframes by taking the mean between the columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, concatenation

I am working with Pandas DataFrames and looking to take the mean between two of them. I am looking to take the mean between columns with the same names.
For example

**df1**

```
    time     x    y     z
 0     1  1.25  2.5  0.75
 1     2  2.75  2.5  3.00
 2     3  1.50  2.5  1.25
 3     4  3.00  2.5  3.50
 4     5  0.50  2.5  2.25
```

**df2**

```
    time     x    y     z
 0     2  0.75  2.5  1.75
 1     3  3.00  2.5  3.00
 2     4  1.25  2.5  0.25
 3     5  3.50  2.5  2.00
 4     6  2.25  2.5  2.25
```

and the result I am looking for is

**df3**

```
    time     x    y     z
 0     1  1.25  2.5  0.75
 1     2  1.75  2.5  2.375
 2     3  2.25  2.5  2.125
 3     4  2.125 2.5  1.875
 4     5  2.00  2.5  2.125
 5     6  2.25  2.5  2.25
```

Is there a simple way in Pandas that I can do this, using the merge function or similar? 
I am looking for a way of doing it without having to specify the name of the columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('time', as_index=False).mean()
print (df)
   time      x    y      z
0     1  1.250  2.5  0.750
1     2  1.750  2.5  2.375
2     3  2.250  2.5  2.125
3     4  2.125  2.5  1.875
4     5  2.000  2.5  2.125
5     6  2.250  2.5  2.250
```

Comment: Would pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer').mean(axis=1) do the same, or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @Uvar - unfortunately not, because get columns after `merge` - `['time_x', 'x_x', 'y_x', 'z_x', 'time_y', 'x_y', 'y_y', 'z_y']`

Comment: Thank you! I had tried this but forgotten the square brackets [] around df1, df2 @jezrael

Comment: @Uvar your operation results in one single column remaining. 
0    1.56250
1    2.71875
2    2.03125
3    3.25000
4    2.90625

Comment: Then I was mistaken indeed. Thanks for the extra insight! :)

Comment: @CatD - Glad can help!